# Getting 400 Error in wordpress website

Tags: plugins, posts, permalinks

When I go to my blog page and click on one of the topics from the table of contents. Note the table of contents is made by using a plug in that takes all the  element and make the toc.
https://www.scrapingdog.com/blog/csharp-html-parser/

Now after that if I click on back button on browser, it shows 400 error which vanishes if I reload.
This problem only exists if I keep my permalinks option to "Postname". Once I change it to "Month and name" it works completely fine.
What should I do keep using post name permalink and the page also keep on working.

Comment: Does the same issue occur for regular anchor links if you disable the TOC plugin? If it only occurs for links from the plugin then you’ll need to ask its author for assistance.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate the issue in Safari, but in Chrome I found an error that seems to identify "Turbolinks" as the culprit. You'll need to raise this issue with them, or whoever has implemented it.